# Can we Delete uploaded files from dam

Tags: adobe, aem

I need to delete uploaded files from DAM Asset programmatically. Can we delete particular file node from DAM?

Path:-
`/content/dam/nextgen/Ehub-POD/....`

Inside Ehub-POD , I'm creating a folder and upload files. In jsp page I'll select particular file and need to delete the file from dam as well as from the jsp.

Comment: what do you mean **" delete the file from dam as well as from the jsp."**. JSP will not store anything. the storage of the Assets data will be in that particular path where you have created/uploaded. you can write a code to delete that particular node and save back the session.

Comment: are you trying to **delete a node in DAM from JSP code** ?

Comment: To delete a node in DAM from java.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Imagine we have the following image in dam:

```
/content/dam/nextgen/Ehub-POD/image1.jpg
```

To remove it use `jcr Session`:

```
session.removeItem("/content/dam/nextgen/Ehub-POD/image1.jpg")
if (session.hasPendingChanges()) {
    session.save();        
}
```

Image from dam will be removed, now you need to run query to find out where image was used and delete `fileReference` property:

```
Workspace workspace = session.getWorkspace();
QueryManager qm = workspace.getQueryManager();
Query query = qm.createQuery("/jcr:root/content/websitename/*[@fileReference='/content/dam/nextgen/Ehub-POD/image1.jpg']", Query.XPATH);
QueryResult queryResult = query.execute();
result = queryResult.getNodes();
while (result.hasNext()) {
    Node node = result.nextNode();
    node.getProperty("fileReference").remove();
}
```

or you can delete all info about image, received
 node store info about cropping, fileReference and etc:

```
while (result.hasNext()) {
    Node node = result.nextNode();
    node.remove();
}
```

and don't forget to save your repository changes

```
if (session.hasPendingChanges()) {
    session.save();        
}
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply. I've done removing the asset node using asset manager.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it via CURL:

You can do a CURL DELETE request to the image path to remove it. Also, you can find all references to an image using CURL via following command:

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/wcm/references.json?path=/content/dam/nextgen/Ehub-POD/test-image.png
```

> This will give you references of all the places where this image is used  (except CSS or JS).

Comment: This is not a solution that is required here.